# How to extract or find executable code in memory dump?

Tags: memory, computer-forensics

When I analyze malware, I need disassembly code on malware.

So I try memory forensics to find executable code in memory dump.

I use volatility, Windbg, other forensic tools, ...But I can't find executable code anywhere..:(

Please help me.
How to find executable code using memory dump file???

Comment: Malware, by its very nature, won't make itself easy to find, and there will be no single method to find it. I'm not sure that this sort of question actually fits within the scope of this site. Have you looked at [security.se]? Check their help centre before posting there.

Answer (score 0):

Finding malware in a memory dump is a very hard process. Malware can be crypted, which will then result in no matches when looking for an executable. This is likely the case.

Without reversing any packing/encryption, you won't find the executable code.

I would recommend watching this series [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VroEiMOJPm8)

about decrypting and reverse engineering programs.